# How to send post request to Wordpress rest api have custom fields?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to send a post request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` that have custom fields to it.

What happens is the request field get successfully but the custom fields did not get updating with data I send!!

I just receive an empty string in each custom field that I have to do the following filter to show them in rest API in the first place ( custom fields not showing by default in rest api )

```php
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
  $_data = $data->data;
  // My custom fields that I want to include in the WP API v2 responce
  $fields = ['fifu_image_url', 'fifu_image_alt'];

  foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $_data[$field] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field, true );
  }

  $data->data = $_data;
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

if I post something from the Wordpress panel and entered a value in the custom field they show on rest API!!

So why I can't send a post request? just get request working?!

if there any hook to enable this I'll be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I already given a good explanation into other thread to use the Custom fields into POST Rest API call: 
[Populate ACF Fields using Wordpress Rest API JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553090/populate-acf-fields-using-wordpress-rest-api-js/56556671#56556671)

Hope it helps!

Thanks