# Wordpress Rest Api Update content with POST on custom endpoint

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating a custom endpoint for Post Type Post.
The request from Javascript work fine, but  can't understand how update, for example, the content of a post.

I've created and registered a route, i've created a callback function for a route and i've created a little form where i insert the post ID and the content.

This is the Code For Route

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'postsAdd/(?P<id>\d+)', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' =>'wl_post_write',
    ]);
})
```

This is the callback function

```
function wl_post_write( $request ) {
    $parameters = $request->get_params();
    return $parameters;
}
```

The XMLHTTPRrequest from javascript is

```
    var ourPostData = {
        "content": content
    }

    var updatePost = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    updatePost.open("Post", mySiteData.siteURL + '/wp-json/wl/v1/postsAdd/'+id+'/?post_type=post');

    updatePost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", mySiteData.nonce);

    updatePost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    updatePost.send( JSON.stringify(ourPostData) );

    console.log(updatePost.responseText);
```

Variables "content" and "id" is the value i write inside the form field.

The console.log of responseText is:

```
    {"id":"51","post_type":"post","content":"my new post content"}
```

The code Above return the correct parameters i sent with the request, but this not update the content inside the post with id 51.

I can't understand how update it.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You require to pass the Authorization with your request. Refer this thread to pass the correct authorization for custom rest endpoint with POST methods: [Populate ACF Fields using Wordpress Rest API JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553090/populate-acf-fields-using-wordpress-rest-api-js/56556671#56556671)

Thanks

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer. I use this updatePost.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + param ); where param is a encode base64 of username:password. 

This authorizzation work with wordpress deafault API Rest with POST.

Anyway, with authorizzation too  the post weren't updated

Comment: Would you be able to update your code snippets with authorization you are doing? 
Also I would like to know whether GET method is working for you?

Comment: The default wordpress endpoints with POST method works with that authorizzation- I'm able to create and update posts. From a custom endpoint it seems that the authorization works but not the update of the post.
GET Methods work fine with default and custom endpoint too.