# How to send a POST request with Advanced Custom Fields data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to send a post request to the rest api with some custom fields. THis is my code

```
                let newCharacter = {
                    'title': $('.create-char-name').val(),
                    'acf': {
                        'char_class': $('#char-class').val(),
                        'char_subclass': $('#char-subclass').val(),
                        'char_level': $('#char-level').val()
                    },
                    'status': 'publish'
                }

                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', spbk_data.nonce);
                    },
                    url: spbk_data.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/character/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: newCharacter,
                    success: (response) => {
                        console.log("congrats");
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: (response) => {
                        console.log("Sorry");
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

The request goes through without any problems, but when I check the json, the "acf" field returns false.
I'm using the [acf to wp api plugin](https://github.com/times/acf-to-wp-api), if that information is useful.

The only info I found about this issue was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553090/populate-acf-fields-using-wordpress-rest-api-js), but I don't really understand what the answer meant. I tried adding `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', application/json);` (I also tried with lower case initials), below the nonce, like the post seems to suggest, but that returns this error:

`"{"code":"rest_invalid_json","message":"Invalid JSON body passed.","data":{"status":400,"json_error_code":4,"json_error_message":"Syntax error"}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
function NewCharacter(){

    this.title;
    this.acf;
    this.status;
}

function CharInfo(){

    this.char_class;
    this.char_subclass;
    this.char_level;

}       

var charInfo = new CharInfo();
charInfo.char_class=$('#char-class').val();
charInfo.char_subclass=$('#char-subclass').val();
charInfo.char_level=$('#char-level').val();

var newCharacter = new NewCharacter();
newCharacter.title=$('.create-char-name').val();
newCharacter.acf=charInfo
newCharacter.status="publish";

$.ajax({
     beforeSend: (xhr) => {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', spbk_data.nonce);
     },
     url: spbk_data.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/character/',
     method: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(newCharacter),
     success: (response) => {
         console.log("congrats");
         console.log(response);
     },
     error: (response) => {
         console.log("Sorry");
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Comment: Or, try to use directly JSON.stringify(newCharacter), with your solution. You should pass the JSON string , not the Object itself

Comment: That didn't work. I tried with both your and my solution, but they return an empty object

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm kinda dumb. I tried [another plugin](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api) to make the bridge between acf and the rest api, and it worked.

It came to my mind many times to try another plugin, but I thought "they do the same thing, there's no point in trying that". It goes to show that you shouldn't just brush off solutions that seem too obvious or stupid.