# Insert ACF data in Wordpress custom post type through REST API (front-end)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, fetch-api, advanced-custom-fields

My goal is to be able to insert data using JavaScript fetch method.

Inserting the post worked like a charm,
but I can only insert the post `title` and `status`.
How can I insert ACF data?

```
fetch('http://mywebsite.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/athletes/',{
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.state.userToken}`
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({
        title: 'my custom post title',
        status: 'publish',
        acf: {
          my_field: 'my acf value here'
        }
    })
}).then( (response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then( (post) => {
    console.log(post);
});
```

Comment: @Sohrab my attempt is javascript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out!
answer here: [Populate ACF Fields using Wordpress Rest API JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553090/populate-acf-fields-using-wordpress-rest-api-js)

I just had to change "acf" for "fields" inside the object.